# OpenJDK 17 / Java flight recorder license

Tags: java, jfr, openjdk-17

I'm using openjdk 17 in production and I would like to use Java Flight Recorder tool but I cannot find precise information if I can use it for commercial purposes.

I found that in Java 8 there is an information that this tool is commercial and requires additional JVM parameters(-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures)

I cannot find the same information for OpenJDK 17, for example in this article: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/17/pdf/using_jdk_flight_recorder_with_openjdk/openjdk-17-using_jdk_flight_recorder_with_openjdk-en-us.pdf it seems that "XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures" is not required.

[image]

Does anyone know what is the license of this tool in OpenJDK 17 version ?

Comment: And from [JEP-328](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328): _Flight Recorder has existed for many years and was previously a commercial feature of the Oracle JDK. This JEP moves the source code to the open repository to make the feature generally available._